# Site for 3 different target audiences

Tags: landing-page, customisation, audience

We are working on a service that is quite new and unknown to people. It's is oriented on small business. The target audience is divided into 3 specific different groups. As for now, we have one landing page, which communicates to 3 groups.

We have very low conversion mainly because people don't understand how they can use the service and benefit from it.

So, we decided to change the logic:

There will be one entrance page, where user will have to choose his group (1 of 3) and then he will be forwarded to the page of the group he chose before, where all the explanations how to use the service are provided.

So instead of one page we will have four pages. Will it improve the communication with users and are there any suggestions how to deal with 3 different target audiences?

Comment: Will users know immediately which group they belong to, or will they need to compare the groups in order to decide which one is most suitable?

Comment: They will know. The groups will be something like:

1) Tourists
2) Real estate agents

and so on

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, giving the user straight options won't help. For example - I could be  a real-estate agent on a tour (making me both a tourist and a real-estate agent), so which one should I chose on your site?

**The "thing" you need here is a Natural language UI**, give the user a short paragraph, let him fill in some blanks that best describes his visit to the site, take him to a logical page w.r.t. his selections.

example:
http://escapeflight.com/
[image]

If you want an open source tutorial / implementation of the above example go here
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/21/natural-language-form-with-custom-input-elements/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Why not make the main page do the separation for you? Use nice big box/tiles/whatever to **let the user decide why they are there on the site**.

Here is how codeacademy labs divides it language platforms:

[image]

Here is how cydia lets you setup your environment based on your area of interest:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly how we are doing, but i'm afraid that people will click "Create an acccount" button instead of tiles

Comment: @Oleg This was a long time ago but I'd love to hear your experience. I am faced with a similar issue with two groups. I thought that I could hide the "create account" button until a choice was made by clicking one of the tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just a gateway page where you force users to choose a group before seeing any information, I would present an introduction to the overall proposition on that page, including an overview of the top-level benefits for each user group, and then link through to full details written specifically for each group on separate pages.

Bear in mind that some people will (ideally) arrive directly on those group-specific landing pages from search engines, so the content on those pages is really your main priority.

Comment: The main benefits will be written in the headline and description and they are similar for all the 3 groups. The difference for 3 groups is how to use service to get this benefits and it is explained in each page individually.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use action sentences to select a profil. For instance:

- I'm a tourist: I'm visiting the city
- I'm a real estate agent: I'm looking for houses to add to my collection
- ...

Improve on the above suggestion by **giving the user the option to select "his role", "purpose" and "nature of visit" to the site** - to get the best content served to him (more in this post https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/41122/13276)

also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_user_interface

Answer (score 0):

Agree to Matt, users should do concious choise. Use [AIDA (Attention Interest Desire Action)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIDA_%28marketing%29) technique to help users to select valuable proposition, not just label options.

Comment: They will be there, of course. Just forgot to mention them.

Answer (score 0):

For something that has to target groups as different as Tourists and Real estate agents I would create multiple completely segregated sites.

There is no overlap in search terms so that shouldn't be an issue. Temporarily have a splash page that redirects to the proper page and sort locally the default redirect is the user opts int then take that down after people are arriving directly where they should be.

> We have very low conversion mainly because people don't understand how
>   they can use the service and benefit from it.

It is important for your page to reflect the search terms that being people to that page. If people search tourist location in city X and you take them to a splash screen that's bad UX. Sites separated by topic allow users jump directly to what they are searching for.